# Gradle sync failing after i reinstalled android studio

Tags: java, android

I want your help in fixing this gradle sync error in my project that I made before reinstalling android studio.
So far I have tried changing *sdk* and *jdk* path in settings and project structure.

I am attaching some screenshots below in no order:-

[image: My sdk location & jdk version]
[image: Build results]
[image: Event log]
[image: sdk tools in settings]

Build gradle in case:-

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mathon.fingers"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.4"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using compileSdkVersion 29 but in the screenshot API Level 29 is not installed. So you can either install API level 29 or Just change "compileSdkVersion 29" to "compileSdkVersion 30".

Go to Android SDK, Select Android 10 (Q) and click Apply. This will fix your problem.

Comment: i have tried what you suggested, but now i am getting the following error . ```Could not create an instance of type sync_studio_tooling2_co8upjsfwns6zij9wodmtr0jp.
> Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
```

Comment: Did you install API Level 29?

Comment: not yet but i am installing it now , hope it will this issues